# Javascript - redirect to another website and call Javascript function after that page loads

Tags: javascript, html, css, redirect, browser

**Scenario:** you have a link to another website (say yahoo.com) on your webpage, and a user clicks the link.

Can you have Javascript functions be called and HTML/CSS be loaded on the page even though it's on a totally different domain? Like, rendering some sort of sidebar on Yahoo?

If not (which I assume is the case), are there other ways of doing this?

Comment: You can put Yahoo.com in an `<iframe>` element, but you won't be able to interact with the DOM.

Comment: @Blender: Odds are *very* high that Yahoo uses a frame buster.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: It probably does, but I'm just suggesting the <iframe> as a (not very usable) solution. Although I think it is possible to work around frame busting.

Comment: @Blender: Not a decent framebusting script (and you can be *sure* Yahoo has one), no.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is **NO**, you cannot.

You can of course do workarounds, like Blender suggest in his comment, embedding an iframe with the site, but due to the [same-origin policy](http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy) you will not be allowed any access to the content loaded within the iframe if it originates from another domain. That goes for both CSS and JavaScript, so you will not be able to modify the content in any way.

Tha said, you could perhaps load the content in an iframe and have a "sidebar" on your own page, along side the iframe. When you click on any link in your "sidebar" you load that reference within the iframe, creating a "feel" that the sidebar relates to the content of the iframe. It is in no way a great solution, but it is the closest I can think of at the moment.

**Update**

Extended the example provided by @kieran in his comment, with a few links, so here is a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/UMw3T/) of what I described above.

Your DOM would look similar to this:

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <a href="http://images.yahoo.com/" target="container">Yahoo images</a><br/>
    <a href="http://news.yahoo.com/" target="container">Yahoo news</a>
</div>
<iframe name="container" class="site-container" src="http://www.yahoo.com/" />
```

And some CSS that you could modify to fit your needs:

```
.sidebar {
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #ccc;
    border-right: 1px solid #888;
}

.site-container {
    border: 0;
}

.sidebar,
.site-container {
    height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: [Here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nvnbr/) demonstrating the iframe I made after I got to wondering if yahoo did have any anti frame mechanisms after all:

Comment: @kieran Thanks for that, tried to update my answer with a link to an extension of your example, where i added a few links to the side bar, but SO complain about the JSFiddle link for some reason. So I'll post it here instead. [Extended example](http://jsfiddle.net/nvnbr/2/)